# How to get nodeunit to detect and run tests included in subfolders?

Tags: node.js, nodeunit

I have the following folder structure to my nodeunit tests for a particular project:

```
/tests
/tests/basic-test.js
/tests/models/
/tests/models/model1-tests.js
/tests/models/model2-tests.js
```

My question is - how do I get nodeunit to automatically execute ALL of the tests in the **tests** folder, including the sub-directories contained within?

If I execute **nodeunit tests** it only executes basic-test.js and skips everything in the sub-folders by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `make` based magic (or shell based magic).

```
test: 
    nodeunit $(shell find ./tests -name \*.js)
```

Here your passing the result of running `find ./tests -name \*.js` to `nodeunit` which should run all javascript tests recursively

Comment: I'm working on Windows primarily, have an example that would work for that?

Comment: Actually, I can figure that out with Powershell

Comment: Ideally though, I would like to have a configuration-based solution to attack this so I don't have to force anyone to remember to run the scripts that way.

Comment: @Aaronontheweb configuration is called `npm test` which works cross platform

Answer (score 1):

Nodeunit allows you to pass in a list of directories from which to run tests. I used a package called diveSync which synchronously and recursively loops over files and directories. I store all the directories in an array and pass it to nodeunit:

```
var diveSync = require("diveSync"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    nodeUnit = require('nodeunit'),
    directoriesToTest = ['test'];

diveSync(directoriesToTest[0], {directories:true}, function(err, file) {
    if (fs.lstatSync(file).isDirectory()) {
        directoriesToTest.push(file);
    }
})

nodeUnit.reporters.default.run(directoriesToTest);
```

Comment: I recommend this approach because you can run this script with nodemon and automatically re-run the tests on file changes

Answer (score 0):

While this is not an *automatic* solution as described above, I have created a collector file like this:

*allTests.js:*

```
exports.registryTests = require("./registryTests.js");
exports.message = require("./messageTests.js")
```

When I run `nodeunit allTests.js`, it does run all the tests, and indicates the hierarchical arrangement as well:

```
? registryTests - [Test 1]
? registryTests - [Test 2]
? messageTests - [Test 1]
```

etc...

While the creation of a new unit test file will require including it in the collector, that is an easy, one-time task, and I can still run each file individually. For a very large project, this would also allow collectors that run more than one, but not all tests.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for solutions for the same question. None of the presented answers fully suited my situation where:

- I didn't want to have any additional dependencies.
- I already had nodeunit installed globally.
- I didn't want to maintain the test file.

So the final solution for me was to combine Ian's and mbmcavoy's ideas:

```
// nodeunit tests.js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// Add folders you don't want to process here.
const ignores = [path.basename(__filename), 'node_modules', '.git'];
const testPaths = [];

// Reads a dir, finding all the tests inside it.
const readDir = (path) => {
    fs.readdirSync(path).forEach((item) => {
        const thisPath = `${path}/${item}`;
        if (
            ignores.indexOf(item) === -1 &&
            fs.lstatSync(thisPath).isDirectory()
        ) {
            if (item === 'tests') {
                // Tests dir found.
                fs.readdirSync(thisPath).forEach((test) => {
                    testPaths.push(`${thisPath}/${test}`);
                });
            } else {
                // Sub dir found.
                readDir(thisPath);
            }
        }
    });
}

readDir('.', true);
// Feed the tests to nodeunit.
testPaths.forEach((path) => {
    exports[path] = require(path);
});
```

Now I can run all my tests, new and old, with a mere `nodeunit tests.js` command.

As you can see from the code, the test files should be inside `tests` folders and the folders should not have any other files.